# Can Xtext validate randomly typed words

Tags: xtext

In Xtext is it possible to know the word typed randomly and can make use of it for validation.I just appended super in place of the method name. So i can use it anywhere((superType=[method])?')  anywhere. But what required is, it should not give its name in its corresponding method. i.e., method 1  should get method 2, method 3 and so on but not method 1.
Here is my example.
    class.method1
    { `enter code here`
    };

```
Class.method2
{ `enter code here`
};
```

Comment: is the a question the the grammar or on the validation on a grammar you already have

Comment: On the Validation of the grammar already i had.

Comment: And how does this section pf the grammar look like